# in Recursion : Why the last line is Sequentially ascending not descending in this code

Tags: java

if i pass a 5 as parameter value 
I think the last line must arranged ascending not descending
In short, if you explain it, I will be thankful !!

```java
public void rec(int val)
{
    if(val == 0)
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < val ; i++)
        System.out.print("*");

    System.out.println("#");

    rec(val - 1);

    System.out.println("No." + val);
}
```

Current output:

```
*****#
****#
***#
**#
*#
No.1
No.2
No.3
No.4
No.5
```

Comment: Because println(5) it's called *after* you've called rec(4), which calls println(4) after calling rec(3), etc.

Comment: @Mahmod Please try and explain more clearly. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
public void rec(int val)
{
    if(val == 0)
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < val ; i++)
        System.out.print("*");

      System.out.println("#");
      System.out.println("No." + val);
      rec(val - 1);
```

otherwise the System.out.println in the lowest rec will be the first to get called and then back up

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think you want to know how recursion works. Generally all the methods execute on stack. And the local variables of a method and parameter values of a method are in the scope of a stack.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OmRGjbyzno) video that explains factorial in recursion with nice visuals of stack. You will understand why your code behaves the way it does.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8-ht2AKyH4) video on what is stack/heap etc.

Though the video is on C++, the base concepts of method execution in stack is same.